# An algorithm to solve the postage stamp problem recursively

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, discrete-mathematics

Here is a mathematical problem known as the “postage stamp problem”. You need to put a certain number of cents of postage on an envelope ( **amount** ). 
There is room on the envelope for only **n** stamps (but no more).

There is a list of the available denominations of stamps (**denominations**). You can use as many of each denomination as you need. The goal is to get the required **amount** with the **denomination** and limited **n** stamps.

For example, for **amount** =12, **n** =3, and **denominations** =<<9 5 2>> you can do it with 5+5+2. But you could not make **amount** =17 at all.

How could I solve this recursively?

I have been able to identify the base case. For example, when you go over the value limit, or you run out of places to put a stamp, those are failed attempts, when you reach the goal, that is a positive attempt that should return true. 
And the trick to the recursion is finding the sum of all the possible combination.

An algorithm or a slight hint of the code in java would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you show some attempt?

Comment: Use forever stamps.

Comment: @TerryDorsey I was able to identify the base case. For example, when you go over the value limit, or you run out of places to put a stamp, those are failed attempts, when you reach the goal, that is a positive attempt that should return true. And the trick to the recursion is finding the sum of all the possible combination

Comment: If you first try to take one 9-stamp the remaining can be seen as new simplified problem `amount=3, n=2`.

Comment: Also, "you could not make amount =17" is **wrong** in reality. Two 9 cent stamps. You've overpaid by one cent, but that is only two stamps and the postal service will happily accept your overpayment.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch the goal is reach the exact amount. Not above or below

Comment: @nerd Fascinating. BTW, have you checked your schools' honor code as regards to help from third-parties on assignments?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yes i can get help as far as I don't copy other people's code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a kind of subset-sum problem.

Recursive function should provide:

```
 stop condition: 
     when sum is zero and left count is zero - success
     when sum is zero and left count is non-zero - fail
     when sum is negative - fail
 traverse possible variants to solve simpler problem at the next recursion level:
     for every stamp value v check - 
       is it possible to make solution using value v and result of recursive call for count n-1
  (note: to avoid duplicate solutions, start traversal from the same stamp index, omitting lower indexes)
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is a brute-force solution, something as simple as this would work:

```
Solve(amount, denoms[1...m], partial[1...n], pos, sum)
1. if sum = amount then print partial[1...n], pos - 1
2. if pos <= n then
3.    for i = 1 to m do
4.       partial[pos] = denoms[i]
5.       Solve(amount, denoms[1...m], partial[1...n], pos + 1, sum + denoms[i])
6.    partial[pos] = 0
```

The way to use this is by making the call `Solve(amount, denoms[1...m], partial[1...n], 1, 0)`. This will print all solutions along with the length of each solution encountered. Note that this will print out all permutations of every solution, so it is doing a fair amount of unnecessary work; also, it's continuing the recursion even after it overshoots the amount. Both of these issues can be fixed with a few extra lines of code - only make the recursive call if the current sum is less than or equal to the amount, for instance, and keep track of the smallest denomination used so far and only use denominations of that size or smaller - but those performance improvements will not change the method's performance in an asymptotically meaningful way (i.e., these don't make the algorithm polynomial-time). Indeed, this problem can probably be pretty easily reduced to an NP-complete problem and so it probably doesn't have an accessible polynomial-time solution.